# Web App not Found-edit in DatasheetView

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, datasheet

i came accross the following error, when my client tries to edit list data through datasheet view from terminal machine.

```
The Web application at xxx could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL 
correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may
need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
```

Note: this error is coming with only 1 list. All other lists are working fine. i m using sharepoint 2007 on 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to alternate access mappings.

I had this issue, and the clue was that the datasheet was referencing a URL of the form:
`_http://hostname/site/...`

instead of

`_http://hostname.domain/site/...`

ie. the datasheet was not referencing the fully qualified domain name (FQDN).
If the error message states `The Web application at _http://hostname/site/...`, ie. the error doesn't use the FQDN, alternate access mapping may resolve it. The end of the error message seems to suggest alternate access mappings, although it is not entirely explicit.

I resolved this by adding an alternate access mapping as follows:

internal url: `http://hostname`

public url: `http://hostname.domain` (FQDN)

Default Zone in my case, should work for other zones.

hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks i already did that, but hvn't mentioned, may b this will help someone else :)